# windows server essentials media pack

Tags: windows, domain, controller, media

I have a server 2012 r2 essential build that is already up that is set up on a workgroup. We cannot use a domain controller for this environment. I am wanting to install the media pack, can I do this without a domain controller?
I am open to any ideas, Thanks.

Comment: what media pack ?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40837

Comment: Just learn something, but yes, its not wrote as a prereq. Most device that can accept a media stream are not domain joined too, so it would not make sense to need an AD to configure